# Capybara 1.1.4 -> 2.1.0 upgrade causes Poltergeist "ObsoleteNode" errors

Tags: rspec, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I have a working Capybara 1.1.4 test suite running Poltergeist 1.0.2, running atop PhantomJS 1.9.2

Today I've tried to upgrade Capybara to 2.1.0 & Poltergeist to 1.4.1. Most tests work, but a bunch of page.find() elements on js-enabled tests are returning the folllowing error upon .click:

> Capybara::Poltergeist::ObsoleteNode: The element you are trying to
>   interact with is either not part of the DOM, or is not currently
>   visible on the page (perhaps display: none is set). It's possible the
>   element has been replaced by another element and you meant to interact
>   with the new element. If so you need to do a new 'find' in order to
>   get a reference to the new element.

The strange thing is:

- page.find('#my-element') finds the element just fine
- page.find('#my-element').value returns the correct value

BUT

- page.find('#my-element').click returns the above 'ObsoleteNode' error.

Has anyone seen this before? I've spent a few hours going through every crazy theory I can think of, and nothing will get elements to click. (Side-note: "#my-element" is just an example. There are many different elements with many different IDs which are failing to .click)

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Does `click_on('#my-element')` have the same problem? What about `click_on('#my-element', visible: true)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20684899) didn't work for me. I used select_option

```
page.find(:css, "#province").find("option[value='Adana']").select_option
```

Answer (score 1):

I replaced find the element and click on it with just click_on method and this helped me.

```
click_on('My link')
```

instead of

```
find('a', text: 'My link').click
```

But I had an another issue. I had 2 links. I solved it by replacing

```
all('a', text: 'My link').last.click
```

with using context:

```
  within('#overlay') do
    click_on "My link"
  end
```

And that helped.